# Linking to figures in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have some images in my documentation created as a set of reST files in Sphinx. I prefer to keep them pretty small, and I want the user to click on them to get the larger image. The smaller image is not for file size reasons but for presentation reasons. I do not find a syntactic way to combine the tags `image:` or `figure:` with `ref:` or `link:`.

```
.. image:: _static/my_image_small.png
```

and I have a bigger version in the same folder: `my_image_large.png`.

If you come up with a solution, should the larger image just be a file with an explicit link to it or do I create a reST file with an additional image: tag? An alternative could be to play with the image sizes in the reST file, but then I still do not know how to create the link from the small image to the large image. Is there a way to bypass the Sphinx generator and just give the HTML that I want?

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways you can do it.

The first is to just insert a bit of "raw" HTML:

```
.. raw:: html

    <a href=....><img src=....
```

The second is to make the image clickable. That way you can link it to a bigger image:

```
.. image:: _static/my_image_small.png
   :target: _static/my_image_large.png
```

There are more options you can give, btw. See the full list in the [restructured text documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image).